# Laravel - How to pass variable to layout partial view

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I have a partial view in master layout which is the navigation bar. I have a variable `$userApps`. This variable checks if the user has enabled apps (true), if enabled then I would like to display the link to the app in the navigation bar.

homepage extends master.layout which includes partials.navbar

My code in the navbar.blade.php is this:

```
@if ($userApps)
    // display link
@endif
```

However I get an **undefined variable error**. If I use this in a normal view with a controller it works fine after I declare the variable and route the controller to the view. I dont think I can put a controller to a layout since I cant route a controller to a partial view, so how do I elegantly do this?

Comment: use view composers check this exemple : https://github.com/achrafkh/proj/blob/master/app/Providers/viewcomposerprovider.php

Answer (score 29):

What version of Laravel you use? Should be something like this for your case:

```
@include('partials.navbar', ['userApps' => $userApps])
```

Just for a test purpose, I did it locally, and it works:

> routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    // passing variable to view
    return view('welcome')->with(
        ['fooVar' => 'bar']
    );
});
```

> resources/views/welcome.blade.php

```
// extanding layout
@extends('layouts.default')
```

> resources/views/layouts/default.blade.php

```
// including partial and passing variable
@include('partials.navbar', ['fooVar' => $fooVar])
```

> resources/views/partials/navbar.blade.php

```
// working with variable
@if ($fooVar == 'bar')
  <h1>Navbar</h1>
@endif
```

So the problem must be in something else. Check your paths and variable names.

Comment: I use 5.2. I tried this and it still doesn't work. Do I have to add the variable into the @extend from the view to master as well?

Comment: This is working in laravel 8 and its much simpler than the viewcomposer approach...

Answer (score 8):

The other answers did not work for me, or seem to only work for older versions. For newer versions such as Laravel 7.x, the syntax is as follows.

In the parent view:

```
@include('partial.sub_view', ['var1' => 'this is the value'])
```

In the sub view:

```
{{ $var1 }}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have gone through all the answers but below is the best way to do because you can also run queries in serviceProvider.

You need to create a separate service or you can use `AppServiceProvider`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::composer('layouts.admin-layout', function ($view) {
            $view->with('name', 'John Doe');
        });
    }
}
```

In your layout

```
{{$name}}
```

Comment: Why on earth is this the best way? Best way for which specific case I can't find mentioned in the question?

Comment: @shaedrich As per my experience, I think this is the best approach to do. If you have any other solution why don't you post your own answer instead of criticism?

Comment: It's recommended to **explain** your answer especially if you are so convinced that your's is better.

Comment: Excellent work! very tedious...

Comment: Thanks, @Bira. Hope this answer is helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

This approach is very simple:

In **parent view :**

```
@include('partial.sub_view1', ['This is value1' => $var1])
```

In **sub view :**

```
{{ $var1 }}
```

Comment: This is not working for me, it just displays `{{ $var1 }}` literally.

Comment: Late to the party, but if `{{ }}` is displaying strings literally, it's probably because you haven't named your file as a blade file, e.g. `file.blade.php`. This usually happens if you make a filename like `file.php`, as it is the blade syntax which isn't showing. Just adding this now in case it helps anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use view composer to send your variable to partial view.
Check the laravel documentation on laravel.com about view composer.
Also you can check the following link that will help you resolve this problem.
https://scotch.io/tutorials/sharing-data-between-views-using-laravel-view-composers